# Modify exe to launch with command line arguments without creating shortcut

Tags: windows, winapi, firefox

I'm trying to use winapi methods to modify an exe.

I don't know how to do it by hand either so that would be a good start if someone can share that with me then i can try to programatically acheive it.

Basically have this exe: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe".
I copied and pasted it to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\SecondFirefox.exe"

I don't want to make it a shortcut because I get some weird separation issues on the taskbar.

I want to make "SecondFirefox.exe" launch with default command line arguments of `-P "Dev" -no-remote`, is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Not directly, but you can create a .bat file to launch it, and put the parameters in there instead.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I did that, and the icon on the bat was different, however when Firefox launched it was not respecting the icon of the new bat i converted to exe. It would take the icon of the original exe. I even used resource hacker to change the original filename, but its not taking. :(

Comment: you want two exe files each will launch different user and their icons doesn't get combined together on the taskbar. Right?

Comment: Thanks @ameen yes I want to try that. I'm thinking it will solve my problem. Details on my problem: Right now I have two shortcuts, both point to "../firefox.exe" but the second shortcut also has command line arguments, `../firefox.exe -P "Dev" -no-remote`, this causes a second instance of firefox to launch. However the launched firefox'es are not using the icon of the shortcut in the taskbar, they are using the icon of the exe the shortcuts are pointing to.

Comment: That is perfectly normal behavior. The shortcut is not what is running, the exes are running, and the Taskbar uses the icon of the running process.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau is there anyway to trick that? I was thinking of setting `System.AppUserModel.RelaunchIconResource` with this method: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/01/10170113.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not answer your question on how to do it but it should give you a clue about what is going on

Windows use what is called `Application ID` which is an attribute for `windows`,`processes` and `shortcuts`.
Using this `ID` Windows is able to determine how taskbar buttons are associated with windows and applications and how the system decides whether an application needs two taskbar buttons for its different windows or whether multiple applications need to share a single taskbar button.

But these `IDs` can be customized by the applications which means that the application still can specify whether two windows share the same icon or not

I create a small executable then I duplicate it and start them together, the result is each one has its own icon.

But this were not the case with `firefox` when I duplicate the executable

It is likely that firefox is altering the `Application IDs` of all running instances to one application ID and that is why all `firefox` taskbar icons are combined.
with that being said even if you tried to build it on your own, it is not easy to do.

I don't know for sure because I don't want to read the source code but you can still check out if that is Right.

Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx) for more information about taskbar API

Comment: Thanks ameen! This is a real good solution to let me know what's going on. Can you explain a little on where/how is the application looking for the icon to use? Would changing `AppUserModel.RelaunchIconResource` change the icon its associated with? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx i would change it with IPropertyStore: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/01/10170113.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Making a copy of the executable seems like a poor idea. Why should you have two copies of the same thing.

I'd make a launcher program. A very simple program that did nothing more than launch the original executable using the modified command line.

Comment: Thanks David for the reply. Because if you launch Firefox with command line arguments of `-no-remote -P "<name_of_profile_here>"` you can run multiple profiles in parallel https://github.com/Mozilla-Student-Projects/Projects-Tracker/issues/72#issuecomment-32677515 . Now I have a bunch of Firefox icons on my taskbar but they all have the same icon, im trying to make it use a different icon per profile. I tried that launcher, I made a bat file and put inside `@echo off start "" "firefox.exe"` the compiled the bat to exe and gave it icon. it launches it pops open firefox next to it, weirdness.

Comment: I honestly don't understand that comment. Make a simple program that calls CreateProcess passing whatever command line arguments you like.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed your reply. I commeted the topic post above it may help please: [#comment44174230_27882708](#comment44174230_27882708)

Comment: The answer you accepted does not answer the question that you asked.